# How can I change value of variable in side method from anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, android

How can I change the value of a variable inside the method from anonymous inner class, to access this variable it must be a `final`, but if the variable final can't change its value, how solve this problem using java?

This is My Code, I want to change the value of `addFlag`.

```
public static boolean addUser(UserModle user){
    Boolean addFlag ;
    dbUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");

    Task task = dbUser.child(user.getId()).setValue(user);
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            addFlag  = true;
        }
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
    return addFlag;
}
```

Comment: Your usage is flawed as the `onSuccess()` might be called long after the boolean was returned. The caller won't see the change

Comment: You could also use an AtomicBoolean I believe

Comment: The method returns immediately, perhaps before the task has completed, so the flag would never be set anyway. This may not be what you want.

Comment: Can you please check my answer?

Comment: I checked your answer and Implement it in my project. Thank you @ReazMurshed

Comment: Awesome! Great to know that I could help!

Comment: Awesome, Thank you for helping. now I delete items in RecyclerView from Firebase all items are delete well, but the last one delete from firebase only and don't delete from recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the current implementation of the `addUser` function is flawed. As per my understanding, you want to know if the user was added successfully to your firebase database based on the `addFlag` value that is returned from this function.

The `addFlag` will be updated once the Firebase database call will get back the data from the firebase realtime database. However, you are returning the flag immediately and hence you are not waiting for the result from your background network thread.

In order to achieve that, I would like to suggest an `interface` based implementation. You might have an `interface` as follows.

```
public interface FirebaseListener {
    void onSuccess(boolean flag);
}
```

Then add an extra parameter in your `addUser` function to pass that `interface` from your `Activity` or `Fragment` where you are calling this function. Hence the function might look as follows.

```
// Change the return type to void, as we are not expecting anything from this function. 
// Instead, we will wait for the success callback using the interface
public static void addUser(UserModle user, FirebaseListener listener) {

    dbUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");

    Task task = dbUser.child(user.getId()).setValue(user);
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            listener.onSuccess(true);
        }
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            listener.onSuccess(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Now implement the listener in your activity or fragment as follows.

```
public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirebaseListener {
    // ... Other functions of your activity 
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(boolean flag) {
        if (flag) {
            // User add successful. Do something here
        } else {
            // User add not successful. Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Now while calling the `addUser` function, you should pass the callback listener along with it as follows.

```
addUser(user, this);
```

I hope that helps.